# Style Post Differently In Query

Tags: query

Hi I'm using the query below to display 7 post from a certain tag, but I'm having a problem. I want to style the first post one way and the next 6 post differently.  What I have noticed is that it shows the thumbnail to the first post the after that it shows the title to the first post and the other 6 post follow with just titles.

What I want to accomplish is showing the thumbnail and title for all post in the query, but I want to style the first post a certain way and the following six different from the first.

I have played around with this query, what am I doing wrong or missing.

```
<?php
$queryObject = new  Wp_Query( array(
'showposts' => 7,
'post_type' => array('post'),
'tag_slug__and' => array('featured-music'),
'orderby' => 1
));

// The Loop
if ( $queryObject->have_posts() ) :
$i = 0;
while ( $queryObject->have_posts() ) :
    $queryObject->the_post();
    if ( $i == 0 ) : ?>
<div id="first-post">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf(__( 'Read %s', 'wpbx' ), wp_specialchars(get_the_title(), 1)) ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('sidethumbs'); ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif; ?>
   <div id="lateststitle"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
</div>
    <?php if ( $i == 0 ) : ?>
</div>
    <?php endif;
    $i++;
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an array for the class of the div, and then inser the value of that variable as a class in the div. And create those classes in your stylesheet.

In your code, the_thumbnail is inside the if($i==0), so it only prints when $i==0. Then the what's outside the if prints just titles, I can't see where you are incrementing $i , so $i is always equals to 0.

This should work.

```
$i = 0;
$class = array("first-post", "posts-below");
while ( $queryObject->have_posts() ) {
    $queryObject->the_post();
    if ( $i == 0 ) { ?>
        <div class=<?php echo $class[0]; ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf(__( 'Read %s', 'wpbx' ),     wp_specialchars(get_the_title(), 1)) ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('sidethumbs'); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php 
         $i++;
     } else { ?>
        <div class=<?php echo $class[1]; ?>>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf(__( 'Read %s', 'wpbx' ),     wp_specialchars(get_the_title(), 1)) ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('sidethumbs'); ?>
                <?php the_title(); ?>    
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php $i++;
 } 


} ?>
```

Comment: That code gave my a syntax error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF)` @Eduardo Sánchez Hidal

Comment: There's no else if in the code. But may be the ":" in the while is causing it. Change the : for { and close with }. I'll edit it.